# GSAP Animation of SVG <symbol> does not update <use>

Tags: jquery, svg, gsap

Why, for example animating the `fill` attribute of an element inside a `<symbol>` using **TweenMax**, has no effect but manipulating it once using **jQuery**'s `attr()` function has?

**[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/MariusUniUlm/pen/OyXaYY)**.

Comment: example please? jsFiddle or codepen.

Comment: @TahirAhmed has been added

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5L031uhj/

Comment: read **[Introducing GSAP 1.18.0](http://greensock.com/gsap-1-18-0)** (under the _Tween complex string-based values_ section), **[AttrPlugin](https://greensock.com/AttrPlugin)** and these **[SVG tips](http://greensock.com/svg-tips)** for more information.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Thank you very much :) the GSAP AttrPlugin solved it

Comment: I think I should post it as an answer for others to get immediate help rather than reading through the comments to find the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[AttrPlugin](https://greensock.com/AttrPlugin)** of **GSAP** is the one that should be used here:

```
TweenMax.fromTo('symbol > rect', 1, {attr: {fill: 'blue'}}, {attr: {fill: 'red'}});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5L031uhj/)**.

*Further reading:*

- [Introducing GSAP 1.18.0](http://greensock.com/gsap-1-18-0).
- [Documentation for AttrPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/).
- [Animating SVG with GSAP](http://greensock.com/svg-tips).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `symbol` tag being a structural element that is not rendered directly with CSS. Only the instances of the `symbol` element referenced through the  tag are. You must animate the attribute of the element instead, with the [GSAP AttrPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/), instead of the [CSSPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/CSSPlugin/)

**MDN SVG Symbol**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol

**W3C Symbol Spec**: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SymbolElement

You can also use the [GSAP AttrPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/) to animate the values of elements inside the  element or  element.

Examples of [GSAP AttrPlugin](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/) used with SVG:

**GSAP SVG FIlter Gaussian Blur**: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/GJPjjQ

**GSAP SVG Filter Hue-Rotate**: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/MwPzox

**GSAP SVG Filter Displacement Turbulence**: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/NqZPwd

I also noticed that your example above does not work in Chrome. But both jQuery and GSAP (without AttrPlugin) change the fill in Firefox, even though it is not standard to the spec. But GSAP AttrPlugin is your best option, since jQuery `attr()` is just a setter and getter method, even using jQuery animate is bad since it uses setTimeout for its animation timing. Whereas the GSAP `to()` method actually animates the values using requestAnimtionFrame (RAF).